# Xcode 12 Firebase Firestore

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the below error in xcode. I'm waiting for your help.

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMAlx.png)

Comment: Did you follow everything listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#ios)?

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question as text. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".